# Java to Kotlin Array conversion, why different in different scenario?

Tags: kotlin

**Scenario 1**
When I Dagger Modules Annotation as below from Java to Kotlin

```
@Module(includes = {AModule.class, XModule.class})
```

It changes to

```
@Module(includes = [AModule::class, XModule::class])
```

**Scenario 2**
However when I convert the below

```
Class<?>[] classArray = {AModule.class, XModule.class};
```

It changes to

```
val classArray = arrayOf(AModule::class.java, XModule::class.java)
```

**Question**
Why does the conversion of `{AModule.class, XModule.class}` differ in the above 2 scenarios, where one is using `[]`, and the other is using `arrayOf` instead?

Comment: Kotlin has no array literals for the normal program code. It is probably a design decision to use explicit function or constructor calls to create an array. In an annotation, function calls aren't allowed so this pseudo-literal notation is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Kotlin 1.2, you can use array literals in annotations. These are not part of the actual Kotlin syntax and only reserved for annotations. This might change in the future but currently you cannot make use of array literals in your actual code.

Read about annotations [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#arrays-as-annotation-parameters).

> For other arguments that have an array type, you need to use the array
>   literal syntax (since Kotlin 1.2) or arrayOf(...):
>
> // Java
>
> ```
> public @interface AnnWithArrayMethod {
>
>     String[] names();
>
> }
> ```
>
> // Kotlin 1.2+:
>
> ```
> @AnnWithArrayMethod(names = ["abc", "foo", "bar"]) 
> class C
> ```
>
> // Older Kotlin versions:
>
> ```
> @AnnWithArrayMethod(names = arrayOf("abc", "foo", "bar")) 
> class D
> ```